# How to numerically rate the beauty of the word?

Tags: english

On the Internet we can find lists like ["The 100 most beautiful words in English"](https://justenglish.me/2015/03/23/the-100-most-beautiful-words-in-english/).

How could I create an algorithm to rate the beauty of any given English word, so that I could run this algorithm and sort any words by their beauty? Currently, I just add points to words with more vowels, but it doesn`t work well.

Comment: How do you define "beauty"?

Comment: here's a python program: `print([w for w in words if woody(w) and not tinny(w)])`

Comment: The best method is probably just to chuck all theoretical ideas, train an AI on words that English speakers rate as beautiful, and use that.

Answer (score 5):

Objectively speaking, words are neither ugly nor beautiful, they just are, but as a sociolinguistic-ish project you could try to determine people's beliefs about word beauty. There are many ways to approach this scientifically: given the link in the OP, the obvious first question is whether there is any disagreement over the most beautiful words. You could collect all of the lists that you can find on the interwebs and see, first, if there is any agreement on what should be on the list. There is an obvious problem that the internet is full of plagiarists, so if there is a most-popular set (by weight), that could be because list A was widely copied.

I suspect that once you control for list copying (especially lists that are exactly the same), there will be nearly zero agreement. However: based on my scan of lists, it is in part inversely correlated with frequency. There is also a strong conceptual basis, so that "love" is likely to be on a list (that could be one of the "universal" words), and "appendectomy" is not likely to be on a list.

Comment: The last point is important. Tolkien wrote in an essay that he heard (or heard of) a Spanish speaker who said that "cellar door" was the most beautiful phrase he had ever heard in English. Most English speaker would not rate it highly, and, while one can't be sure without a controlled experiment, I strongly suspect that their knowledge of the meaning would be part of that judgment.

Comment: In a different field - accents rather than words - there are experimental results. Asked to rate the beauty of different accents, there is a high correlation between the scores that different native speakers assign, and between those scores and the social status of the particular accents. When people who either do not speak the language at all, or who speak it but are not familiar with the acccents, rate them, there is much less correlation among the scores.

Comment: If "the last point is important" (and true), then a partial answer to this question would be to use [sentiment analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentiment_analysis) on words, which I think there are a few libraries with English corpora for.
Obviously it would be unlikely to provide *the* answer (although I think we all agree that doesn't exist, except maybe the OP, but still), but it could form part of such an algorithm.